# Over cooking of baking

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, absorption

Why does a black pan get hotter than a lighter pan in a dark oven?  Everything I've read says that it is the visible light that causes the increased absorption of heat.

Comment: As far as I know I doesn't. Can you cite a source providing evidence that it does?

Comment: @JohnRennie:  I've heard this as "cooking lore" as well, but I don't have a definitive source either.  In the long run, of course, both would reach the same equilibrium temperature with the oven.  But it's not implausible that a dark-colored pan would heat *more quickly* than a shiny one due to the increased absorption of IR radiation from the oven walls (assuming that absorptivity is similar in the visual and the IR);  and faster heating of the pan would affect the qualities of the finished baked good.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: it seems likely to me that heating in the oven is dominated by convection.

Comment: @michael If that was so, the idea of a "convection oven" would be pointless

Comment: @JohnRennie - although various things (biscuit/cinnamon rolls in the refrigerator case at the supermarket) have different temperatures given for 'dark' pans vs glass pans.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not sure how much I agree with that assessment.  Non-convection ovens don't exactly promote a fast airflow.  Steady airflow, sure; but not particularly high convection coefficients.  The element and surfaces in the oven get very warm and have pretty much full view of what you want to heat.  Those two factors suggest pretty high radiation heat transfer.  Also, by searching "dominant heat transfer in an oven" on google, most hits say radiation is the primary mechanism.  They don't seem like heavily researched sources, so I won't say that counts as _proof_; but it is very common.

Comment: @PhilipRoe How would that make a convection oven pointless?  If the primary mechanism of heat transfer in an oven is radiation; that's just a piece of the puzzle.  If you wanted to increase the rate of heat transfer; you can increase the convection.  To me, the implication that radiation is the primary heating mechanism suggests there is room for improving convection so that it's a competing factor.  That's what convection ovens do, and that's why it is able to significantly speed up heating.

Comment: @JMac. Actually, that was precisely the point I was trying to make; that if heating was already dominated by convection it would be a bit pointless to add it as a special feature. But I think I tried to be too clever

Comment: Stainless steel (shiny) is one third as conductive to heat as cast iron. That is a real difference both theoretically and in my experience.